# Ubuntu Apache2 wp_unique_filename response time so slow

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, permissions

I am having difficulties with issue with either file/folder permission setting or wordpress issue.

I have separate user and group for the specific domain and assign all the folders / files for the wordpress except the wp-content folder (for uploads and plugins to work)

However, the site is really slow and according to 'NewRelic's report, it is 'wp_unique_file' that's taking most of the time.

It takes about 20sec to get response from the server.

HOWEVER, when I change owner / group to www-data:www-data for entire directory, it loads up really quick.

I have not had any issue like this.

And there is no error at all either.

Anyone has idea?

Comment: Did you find out what was causing this?  Please update if you did.  Thanks.

Comment: Nope =( I could not. so ended up setting www-data:www-data owner / group